Convert a spark DataFrame to a slighly different case class?
I have some data in HDFS that is in parquet-protobuf.
Due to some project constraints, I want to read that data with a spark DataFrame (easy) and then convert to a case class that is slightly different (i.e. it has the same data, but some fields have a different name, some need to be translated with a dictionary).
I am using Scala, but I guess it doesn't make much of a difference.
Now I can't use .as[CaseClass] as the schema does not match.
I guess I could write a function to transform each Row into my class, but as far as I can tell such a function will need to be written considering the exact order of the fields in the source data, which might be an issue for schema evolution.
Which other options do I have?
Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is a generic solution to this but it uses Spark internal apis (as such the exact code changes between spark versions), but as you note you do need a map to align names to drive it.  The order of the field names used in the select must match the case class field orders so schema evolution is limited by the case class code anyway.
Solution wise, which will not work with Spark Connect, you need to derive the encoder of CaseClass (either via Spark's spark.implicits._ import or frameless) and use this to identify field names:
val enc = implicitly[Encoder[CaseClass]].asInstanceOf[ExpressionEncoder[CaseClass]]
val fieldsInOrderOfCaseClass = enc.schema

the same is true for saving to other schemas.  (NB This should work for bean encoders as well).
Given the schema you can handle the mapping and ordered selects of the columns.
